# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, user-roles, azure-service-principal

I am a guest user in a tenant with owner role in one of the subscriptions. There is an Azure AD app that is created and of which I am an owner. I can see it in my - 'Owned Applications', however, when I open the app it says - **No Access. Insufficient privileges to complete the operation**.
Says the same for all the tabs on the left side. How do I resolve it? What other permission do I need?
[image]

Comment: You might need Application Developer directory role.

Comment: Hi, Does it work?

Comment: @juunas, thanks. That lead me to Azure AD roles and I requested for 'Application Administrator' which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to AzureAD with the account of the global administrator >User settings> Manage external collaboration settings

[image]

[image]

---

**add:**

Another method is to grant guest users the role of `application administrator`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I think this will work but I requested for 'Application Administrator' and I can see now. Out of curiosity, I think your option would grant more privilege than 'Application Administrator' role?

Comment: @YashTamakuwala  There are indeed several ways to do this, such as granting guest users the role of administrator. My answer  is just one of them. I will add other solutions to the answer later, and you can accept it as an answer to help members who have similar problems.

Comment: @YashTamakuwala  No, I think it's the opposite. I think that granting the guest user the application administrator role privilege is more powerful, because it is equivalent to granting the guest user the administrator role at the tenant level, this privilege is still quite large.